# React Native User Login Problem ( AsyncStorage )

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a membership login system but I get an error. I couldn't understand much because I had just started. What's the problem?

```
export default async () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(null);
    const AsyncUserValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid');
    console.log(AsyncUserValue); // (userid 15)
    if(AsyncUserValue != null){
        console.log('AsyncStorageParse: ' + AsyncUserValue); // (userid 15)
        setUserToken(AsyncUserValue);
        console.log('Tokken: ' + userToken); // NULL
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
       setTimeout(() =>{
           setIsLoading(false);
       }, 1000);
    }, []);
    if(isLoading) { return <SplashScreen /> }

    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            {userToken ? (
                <AppTabs />
            ) : (
                <LoginStack />
            ) }
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

[image: Sto]

Answer (score 0):

You returned functional component as asynchronous (note top `export default async ()`).

You can't do that - components are required to return React elements (so they have to be synchronous).

What you can do instead is to create a inner async function and do all your async logic there:

```
export default () => {
  const [state, updateState] = useState();

  async function myWork() {
    const data = await getDataAsyncWay();
    updateState(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    myWork()
  }, [])


  return <View>{...}</View>
}
```

Note: avoid exporting anonymous function as components - this way, their name won't be visible in stack trace (see your screenshot). What you can do instead is:

```
function MyComponent() {...};

export default MyComponent
```